# Can't Connect to Internet, just installed ubuntu

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

I just installed Ubuntu on Dell Mini that I had laying around, and the install went perfectly fine except for the fact that I cannot connect to my wireless internet.

When I click the network button in the top bar it doesn't display any networks to connect to. All it show is:

```
Ethernet Network and disconnected (both grayed out)
VPN Connections, 
Enable Networking (Enabled), 
Connection Information (Grayed Out)
Edit connections
```

I've tried to fix it but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. I might be missing something obvious because I'm new to Linux.

If anyone could help that would be great. Thanks.

Edit: I am running a dell mini with these specs:
Processor: intel Atom CPU N450 @ 1.66GHz x 2
Graphics: Intel IGD
OS-type: 64-bit

With Ubuntu version: 13.04

Comment: Could you please provide us with some more information? What version of Ubuntu are you running? Which Dell Mini do you have?

Comment: i have some problems just like you do. i just installed ubuntu 13.10 and after a lot of trying i finally got into the ubuntu. but then i found that when connected the wireless i still couldn't the Internet via the firefox or terminal though it showed that the wireless had connected successfully.
could you plz tell me what i'm supposed to do? thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try typing this in the terminal
`lspci -vvvnn | grep -A10 -i wireless`
Then look at the output and there should be a line that mentions "kernel driver in use" and then some word like ath9k_htc or something. Then still in the terminal type in
`sudo modprobe <kernel driver>` where you don't write the angle brackets and you instead input the name of that kernel driver like `sudo modrpobe ath9k_htc`
If the output of the first command is blank, just try typing in `lspci -vvvnn` and looking through that for a mention of wireless and find the kernel driver listed underneath that and `sudo modprobe` that driver

Comment: I did exactly what you said but when I did sudo modprobe b43-pci-bridge it responded with: FATAL: Module b43-pci-bridge not found.

Comment: It may not have been compiled into your kernel for some reason =( that seems odd. do a `grep -i b43_pci_bridge /boot/config-3.8.0-31-generic` but tab complete that config file to find the latest one in your /boot folder. This may require some more work if it is not there, but there may be a way to get it as a module... dunno

Comment: I did that and it responded with: /boot/config-3.8.0-generic: No such file or directory

Comment: that's not supposed to be the exact name of your file in /boot Try doing an `ls /boot/` and look for the file that says config with the latest numbers on it.